# Trying to implement a map merge function in Go but failing

Tags: dictionary, merge, go

Most simple reproduction of the issue:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type stringMap map[int]string

func (s *stringMap) Merge(m stringMap) {
    for key, value := range m {
        s[key] = value
    }
}

func main() {
    myMap := stringMap{1: "a", 2: "b"}
    myMap.Merge(stringMap{3: "c"})
    fmt.Println(myMap)
}
```

Why I can't use `key` variable as a key on `mymap stringMap`?

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/mSprMXq5QF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't using indexing (accessing the map) on a pointer to a map.

You just have to make the following change (pay noticed to the removed *):

```
func (s stringMap) Merge(m stringMap) { ... }
```

Comment: Oh, pure distraction. I'm so used to add methods to structs that I automatically used a pointer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could either change the function receiver to a normal receiver (as others have suggested), or dereference it inside the function (`(*s)[key] = value`)

Comment: Do you think this would be better in some way?

Comment: It is the same I guess. Maps (and slices) are already [references to the underlying structure](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps). Using value receiver seems cleaner.

Comment: You might want to use a pointer receiver with a map if you want to replace the map from within the method (e.g. from a `DecodeJSON` method).  But in most cases it isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

The receiver for your `Merge` method is a pointer to a map, which doesn't support the `[]` indexing syntax.  If you change the receiver to `(s stringMap)`, everything should work as you'd expect.